# Finding a quadratic function based on 2 constants

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble figuring out the function of 2 variables [I've drawn a plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEr2g.png).

Basically I want my function $f(x)$ to have 2 constants: m (maximum) and v (variance), and I want it to score best at x = m, and to be 0 at $ m-\frac{v}{2}$, for any given $m$ and $v$.

When I tried playing around with a, b and c on the negative quadratic function, changing any one of those would affect other components.

Is it even possible to achieve this? I also figured out that maybe I could use some kind of $log(x)$ function and doing $x'=m-(x-m)$ if $x>m$ and then calculating $f(x')$

Comment: take a look at the Lagrange polynomial, you should be able to get a parabola that goes thru 3 given points: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: Not enough equations. You need to specify what is the height or what is the area of the figure. Otherwise you can just stretch or shrink the figure in the vertical direction, and you obtain a different quadratic, that also obeys your initial requests. Or maybe I understood this wrong, and you define $f(m)=m$

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for your reply. I realize that, and f(m) is not important for me, I just use f(x) as a scoring function that determines how close x is to m. It could be any value as long as f(m) is maximum of the function.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2892311/265466. You need the other $x$-intercept, but that’s easy to find because they’re symmetric w/r the vertex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can start from the equation for a quadratic: $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$
First, we want it to have a maximum. That means $a<0$. Since you don't care about the height, we can choose $a=-1$. The position of the roots are $$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
The position of the maximum is halfway between the roots at $\frac{-b}{2a}$. What you get then is $$m=\frac{-b}{2a}$$
With $a-1$ you then get $$b=2m$$
Also, from the position of the roots, using $a=-1$, $$v=\sqrt{b^2+4c}=\sqrt{4m^2+4c}$$
This yields $$c=\frac{1}{4}v^2-m^2$$
Therefore the final equation is $$f(x)=-x^2+2mx+\frac{1}{4}v^2-m^2$$

Answer (score 0):

If $f(m)=C$, you can use this function $$f(x)=-C\frac{4(x-m)^2-v^2}{v^2}$$

Comment: I'm sorry but in your case f(x)= m for x=0; what I needed is that f(x) = anything as long as it maximum for x = m; It doesn't matter how much f(m) is as long as its maximum.

Comment: To make Andrej's complaint more explicit, your proposed function is a quadratic in $x$ but it attains its maximum at $x=0$, not at $x=m$.

Comment: @Andrej: I updated the answer to satisfy this

Answer (score 0):

One of the $x$-intercepts of your quadratic is $m-v/2$ and its vertex is at $x=m$, so the other one is at $m+v/2$ since the $x$-intercepts are symmetric with respect to the vertex. These are also its roots, so it’s going to have the form $$a\left(x-m-\frac v2\right)\left(x-m+\frac v2\right).$$ At $x=m$, this has the value $-av^2/4$. Adjust $a$ so that this is the desired peak value.